# Was ember cli 0.2.0-beta.1 released as 0.2.0 resulting in 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token <'?

Tags: ember.js

While trying to figure out how to recreate an ember app which I can't migrate to CLI, and use 'generate' to create resources, and routes with paths and dynamic segments, I was creating and deleting a test app several times. At one point it seems that ember cli tried to update to 0.2.0 and I got warnings about npm packages wanting an older version of node, so I changed the versions in the package json files for those. But when creating a new starter ember app, I get the 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token <' error (update-checker.js, _stream_writable.js, etc).

So I ran 'npm uninstall -g ember-cli' then 'npm install -g ember-cli@0.2.0-beta.1' to get beta back and now I can create starter apps again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue with dependencies being out of line was probably temporary since revisions within CLI are happening so fast. If I came back the next day and cleared out module and component cache and started over, it probably would have cleared up. By reverting CLI manually I wound up with other issues with express live update, so would have to stop and restart express after every edit. I realized I wasn't ready to re-write my gruntfile as a brocfile and deal with all the other issues with migrating to Ember CLI, so started over by updating the Ember dependency in my grunt-based project and going that route, which is also frustrating and hugely problematic, but I'm sure I'm farther along in this route than I would have been in re-writing for Ember CLI.